# Parse.com - How should I structure this data?

Tags: database, parse-platform, backend

I have a music based app I'm building using Parse for the back end. I'm wondering how I should structure my data when it comes to user identities:

- A user can be a regular user, and also a musician, and also a venue owner, etc.

So the idea is that a user can have different identities.
I would love your help on how to best structure this data.

Comment: Please let me know what other details I can provide

Answer (score 0):

You can have a role column in your user table, assign the role based on the user. When the user logs in to the app, you will read his role and based on the role, the ui will be populated. Is this what you are looking for?